# Android show popup after the app has launched 3 times

Tags: java, android, performance, android-intent, android-activity

I would like to build a splash screen in my app, that will only show up after the user has opened the app 5 times, and therefore after.

Does anyone know how I can implement that?

Comment: use sharred pref to store your count value

Comment: U can use database or SharedPreferences to save data

Answer (score 1):

-Hello You can do it by using **Sharedpreferences**

-here is the logic behind it.In your first screen which is launcher activity, put shared preferences and put **Int** variable in it and each time user open the app increase it by +1 and check each time if it is 3 then Launch Your **SplashScreenActivity**

-Useful Shared preference Code:-

```
 SharedPreferences prefobj = getSharedPreferences(
                        "YourprefName", MODE_PRIVATE);

                Editor editor = prefobj.edit();
                editor.putInt("CheckInt", i);
                editor.commit();
```

-Above code is for adding your int value increase i each time

```
SharedPreferences Yourobj = getSharedPreferences("YourprefName",
            MODE_PRIVATE);
    int checkint = Yourobj.getInt("CheckInt", 0);
```

-THis wil give you your value of variable which you are increasing each time

-THanks!

Comment: this is correct for using shared prefs, make a class that extends Application (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) you change your manifest to use the custom application and dump this code in onCreate

Answer (score -1):

```
**Try this:**
```

**In the onCreate() of your first activity write this**

```
 if (isFifthTime()>=5)
                        {
                            Intent i = new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }
                    else
                        {
  SharedPreferences sp =context.getSharedPreferences("yourPrefName", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int openedTimes = sp.getInt("checkInt",0);
        editor.putInt("checkInt", openedTimes+1);
        editor.apply();
            }


            public int isFifthTime()
                {
                    return getSharedPreferences("yourPrefName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("checkInt", 0);
                }
```

Comment: this is wrong, it should be in the application not any activity

Comment: You're right,@tmho.But, in this case,try to understand. he doesn't need this value throughout the application. only when the user opens the app he needs to check. I've tried this in my app and it works like a charm.

Comment: "that will only show up after the user has opened the app 5 times, and therefore after." - OP

yes he does need it throughout the application...  If the OP uses your solution screen orientation changes and phone calls will also add to the counter.